# STRAPI v4 how to refactor schedule post publish from v3 to v4

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

I try to recreate the schedule posts from STRAPI v3 for strapi v4

but I get stuck at the update function, am I missing a filter, some new formating, or params?

config/server.js

```
schedule = require('./controllers/scedulePosts')

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  cron :{
    enabled: true,
    tasks: {
      '*/10 * * * * *': ({ strapi }) => {
        schedule.schedulePublishArticles(strapi)
      }
    }
  }
});
```

/config/controllers/schedulePosts.js

```
module.exports = {
  schedulePublishArticles: async (strapi) => {
    try {
      let draftArticleToPublish = await strapi.api.article.services.article.find(
        { publicationState: 'preview',
          filters: {
            publishedAt: null,
            publishOn: new Date(new Date().setSeconds(0, 0))

          }
        }
      )

       // update publishedAt of articles
      await Promise.all(draftArticleToPublish.results.map(article => {
        return strapi.api.article.services.article.update(
          {id: article.id},
          {publishedAt: new Date()}
        )
      }));

    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message)
    }
  }
}
```

when the update() functions is called with {id = "int"}
it trows this error: "Undefined attribute level operator id"

am I missing some filtering or params structure in update? or is this some kind of bug I V4

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was my update for v4

```
        // fetch articles to publish
        const draftArticleToPublish = await strapi.entityService.findMany('api::article.article', {
            filters: { 
                publishedAt: { $null: true },
                publish_at: { $lt: new Date() }, 
            },
            publicationState: 'preview'
        });
    
        // update published_at of articles
        await Promise.all(draftArticleToPublish.map(article => {
            return strapi.entityService.update('api::article.article', article.id , {
                data: {
                    publishedAt: new Date(),
                },
            });
        }));
```